# show modal without using data-target but with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This is my button on a php file

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-md btnAdd" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Add</a>
```

And I have this script file which aims to open the modal without having the data-target on the button but it doesn't work. How can it be possible to click the button and show the modal without having the attribute data-target?

```
$(".btnAdd").click(function(){

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "process_branch.php",
            data: {},
            success: function(r){
                 $('.modal-content').html(r);
            return false;
            },
            dataType: "html"
        });

        $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

Oh and here is where I put my modal. This is also in another php file. I am trying to create this dynamically

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" data-backdrop="static" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please post your modal html code. because `$('#myModal').modal('show');` it's working for me modal is open.

Comment: The modal is showing because of data-target. I am trying to find a solution to show the modal without it

Comment: what reason do you have to remove the data-target attribute?

Comment: just remove `data-target="#myModal"` and `data-toggle="modal"`  from a tag and then try it's work or not?

Comment: @RenishKhunt its not working

Comment: @madalinivascu because I have to hide the modal after form submission

Comment: use `$('#myModal').modal('hide');` to hide the modal man

Comment: I used that already and it is not working for me

Comment: @D.Gatch why is that?

Answer (score 0):

In following answer i have given model popup in button click.You have to cut that 2 lines into inside of ajax success function.

```
  <a class="btn btn-primary btn-md btnAdd" role="button" data-toggle="modal" ><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Add</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" data-backdrop="static" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">        
           <div class="modal-content" style="padding: 8px;">
           <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
           <span class="popdata">
           </span>
           </div>
        </div>
</div>    

$(".btnAdd").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "process_branch.php",
            data: {},
            success: function(r){
                 // HERE YOU HAVE TO CUT AND PASTE THE LAST 2 LINES
            return false;
            },
            dataType: "html"
        });
        // THESE 2 LINES CUT AND PASTE INSIDE AJAX SUCCESS
        $('.modal-content .popdata').html('hai');
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

Check the 
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mohammedshafeek/3y30exn9/9/)